# Seeking a Proof or a counter example for the following step regarding inequalties

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

Please consider if the following pair of inequalities hold
$$
g(X) \le \mathbb{P}\left(\xi > X \right) \le h(X)
$$
where the domain of integration is over some variable $x$ and $X$ is some constant in this domain.

If $k(x) \ge 0$ is some function will the following hold.

$$
\int_{X}^{\infty}k(x)g'(x)\mbox{d}x \le 
\int_{X}^{\infty}k(x)f_{\xi}(x)\mbox{d}x \le 
\int_{X}^{\infty}k(x)h'(x)\mbox{d}x
$$
where $g'$ and $h'$ represent derivatives of $g$ and $h$ respectively wrt to $X$ and $f_{\xi}$ represents the probability density function of $\xi$.

I think this should be true but someone suggested that it might not be true.

How can we proof that this hypothesis is true, or alternatively what will be a valid counter example which shows this is false.

**edit**

I think i can restate the problem i have, as what are the minimum additional conditions required on $k \ge 0$ such that $\frac{\mbox {d}k}{\mbox {d}x} < 0$ and $k$ is integrable in the domain of integration. So that multiplying it with both sides of an inequality
$$
\int_{X}^{\infty}u(x)\mbox{d}x \le 
\int_{X}^{\infty}v(x)\mbox{d}x
$$
preserves the inequality.

I was thinking of collecting the terms
$$
0 \le 
\int_{X}^{\infty}(v(x) - u(x))\mbox{d}x
$$
and the then try use integration by parts after multiplying with $k$ to show the RHS will be satisfy the inequality, but i was not successful, with that.

If these conditions suffice, how can i show that the inequality is preserved.
Any suggestions or help are most welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Counterexample**: if $k=h\equiv 1$ and $g\equiv 0$, all of the assumptions are satisfied, yet the resulting inequalities read $$0 \le P(\xi>X)\le 0,$$ which is clearly in general false (e.g. take $\xi$ exponential and $X>0$).

Comment: I do not think this counter example is correct. In the example you chose, neither $g$ or $h$ are dependent on $X$.